# How to prove transitivity $xRy \iff y \ge x^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$xRy \iff y \ge x^2$$

How do you find if it is a transitive relation when there is only $$? Isn't transitivity the relation between $2$ conditions, for example $$, $$ therefore $$ ?

I already know that it's not transitive, but I don't understand how to prove it.

Comment: Is your relation defined on $\Bbb R$? (you should make it explicit in your post). If so, find 3 real numbers $x,y,z$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$ hold but not $xRz.$ Since this implies $y^2<y,$ better try some $y\in(0,1)$ (e.g. $y=\frac12$).

Comment: In general, to prove the transitivity of a relation, you have to see if is true that $xRy$ and $yRz \overset{?}{\implies} xRz$

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. $R$ is said to be transitive if  $$\text{Forall }x, y. z\in A, \text{$x$ being related to $y$ and $y$ being related to $z$ implies $x$ is related to $z$}$$ Paying close attention to the quantifiers, you will notice the requirement **Forall$(\forall)$**.

When trying to prove that a certain relation $R$ is not transitive, we are trying to prove the negation of the above statement. In other words, we are trying to prove that the statement $$\text{Forall }x, y. z\in A, \text{$x$ being related to $y$ and $y$ being related to $z$ implies $x$ is related to $z$}$$ is not true. How do we do that? Well, we show that there exist elements $x, y, z$ that satisfy that $xRy$ and $yRz$, but don't imply that $xRz$. Thus, the negation of the above statement becomes $$\text{There exist elements $x ,y, z\in A$ such that $x$ is related to $y$ and $y$ is related to $z$, but $x$ is not related to $z$}$$ So, all you have to do to prove that a certain relation $R$ is not transitive is, find three elements $x, y$ and $z$ such that $x$ is related to $y$ and $y$ is related to $z$, but $x$ is not related to $z$.

Hope this helps!